# How to detect if user has blocked camera?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, camera

How can I detect if user has blocked camera in browser?

I have tried this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(stream) {
    console.log(stream)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

But I get

```
VM1267:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: constraints is not defined
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

I am assuming I should target this exception `NotAllowedError`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually specify the `constraints`:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
  .then(function(stream) {
    console.log(stream)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Syntax) you linked to in your question has more information.

Comment: Ok, but how can I detect is camera is blocked or allowed?

Comment: You should get a `NotAllowedError` if it's blocked. This error can also occur for a variety of other reasons. For the sake of privacy, the reason why you get a `NotAllowedError`  is not further disclosed to you.